# JavaFX. Eliminar el 0 inicial al empezar a escribir en cuadro de texto de calculadora

Tags: javafx, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un cuadro de texto, en JavaFX, quiero que este registre números enteros. No quiero que se introduzcan letras. He creado un evento de tipo tecla en el cuadro de texto y lo he programado para que haya un 0 de partida, similar al 0 de la calculadora. El problema lo tengo que al empezar a escribir toma dicho 0 inicial. Como podría librarme de él?

```
  @FXML
    void limitarTamanioNum(KeyEvent event) {

        try {
            if(txtNumNumeros.getText().equals("")) txtNumNumeros.setText("0");

            txtNumNumeros.setText(removerCeros(txtNumNumeros.getText()));

            int tamanio = Integer.parseInt(txtNumNumeros.getText());
            if (tamanio > 10) {
                ClaseAccesoria.dialogo("No se admiten numeros mayores de 10", ERROR);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ClaseAccesoria.dialogo(ex.getMessage(), ERROR);
        }
    }

 public static String removerCeros(String cadena) {

        cadena = cadena.replace("^0+", "")      ;

        System.out.println(cadena);
        return cadena;
    }
```